# WSO2 IS - "The system cannot find the path specified" when trying to start server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I set the path "JAVA_HOME" and installed WSO2 IS 5.6.0 x64 on Windows 2016 Server. After the installation, I try to start the server via "wso2server.bat", but I get the message "The system cannot find the path specified. The batch file cannot be found". After doing this operation, when I looked into the folder where the server was installed, I noticed that all files are deleted.
Am I doing something wrong? How to correctly run WSO2 Identity Server?

Comment: Try downloading new binary from wso2 site , unzip and then try again.Maybe there is some issue with the binaries which you installed.Once you download a new copy unzip and check if all the folders are available in bin folder

Comment: I have same isssue trying to solve right now

Comment: What issue  are you  facing @dtechlearn?  please check the zip file first as i have downloaded many wso2 products on various OS and i never faced issues, so it's advisable that once you unzip check for files under bin folder

Comment: I have downloaded the wso2 installer which may be the problem... I am now downloading the binary hoping to resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the problem was solved with not downloading the windows x64 installer but rather the binary 
[wso2is 5.6.0 binary](https://wso2.com/identity-and-access-management/install/binary/).

After downloading you just open bin directory and run the wso2server.bat file.
If you need to make it windows service use the [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/)

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for pointing this issue with WSO2 Windows Product Installers. The issue is resolved and updated product installers are now available in [WSO2 website](https://wso2.com/).

You can download WSO2 IS 5.6.0 x64 Windows Installer from [here](https://wso2.com/identity-and-access-management/install). Then install WSO2 IS 5.6.0 on your machine using downloaded '.msi' file. After installation, start the server by clicking on the shortcut that build by the installer. You can find WSO2 IS 5.6.0 shortcut in following location.

*Start Menu -> All apps -> WSO2*

or you can search "Identity Server 5.6.0" in Windows search and click on the shortcut. This will start the WSO2 Identity Server on your machine.

For new WSO2 Products Installers you do not need to set *JAVA_HOME* separately. It contain `jdk1.8.0_192` and if JAVA_HOME is not set, it will automatically set *JAVA_HOME* to `jdk1.8.0_192` and start the WSO2 Product.

[This blog](https://medium.com/@kosalasananthana/how-to-install-wso2-identity-server-f98c9d8b1c81) could be a help for you to understand the installation progress.